# Why doesn't Array#map return the correct array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

When I write something like this:

```
var x = [1,2,3].map(x => { a : 'hello' });
```

I expect to receive something like `[{a:'hello'},{a:'hello'},{a:'hello'}]`, but instead it returns a list of `undefined`s. Why is this?

[image]

Comment: `var x = [1,2,3].map(x => ({ a : 'hello' }));`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "object" is treated as *a block* because [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) have multiple acceptable syntaxes. They includes a block which houses multiple statements:

```
param1 => { statements }
(param1, param2, …, paramN) => { statements }
```

In actuality your current code is interpreted as a block with a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) and a string expression, not an object literal. Thus, your callback doesn't return anything and your array becomes an array of `undefined`s.

Wrap it in parentheses so that it *is an expression* and interpreted as an object literal (because blocks are not expressions, they are statements, and code inside grouping must be an expression):

```
var x = [1,2,3].map(x => ({ a : 'hello' }));
```

Answer (score 3):

You need some parenthesis around the object, otherwise you get a [block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) with a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).

To prevent the block statement in arrow functions, you need to use the [grouping operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping) to get an expression as return value.

```js
var x = [1, 2, 3].map(x => ({ a: 'hello' }));

console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the returned object in parentheses:

```
var x = [1,2,3].map(x => ({ a : 'hello' }));
```

Otherwise, the code in curly braces it is treated as a body of a function.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = [1,2,3].map(x => ({ a : 'hello' }));
```